# Changing font from Roboto regular to Roboto condensed

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I want to change the font of my textview from Roboto regular to roboto condensed. The textView is in a Widget and so i am using a RemoteView. If it is an application we can set it by typeFace. What i need to do for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer now. What we have to do is render the font onto a canvas, and then pass it on to a bitmap and assign that to an imageview

```
 public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) 
{
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"robonto_condunced.ttf");
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setSubpixelText(true);
paint.setTypeface(clock);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(65);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
myCanvas.drawText(time, 80, 60, paint);
return myBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use typeface. Here is an example

```
private void setFonts() { // Setting all fonts
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
            "fonts/DroidSerif-Bold.ttf");
    mMonthTextView.setTypeface(face);
    mAgeTextView.setTypeface(face);
    mHeightAndWeightTextView.setTypeface(face);

}
```

You must put that font in the Assets/fonts/ folder

Comment: I am using a RemoteView for a Widget. So i cant get the textview directly in my code. Can't we directly set the font type in the xml ?

Comment: I think it is not possible. We can only change the style to bold or italic. If you want to do it in xml you have to create a customized textview. But that will take some time to do.